# Django model's managed attributes (@property) с параметрами

Tags: django, django-orm

Есть некая модель с функцией, вызываемой с дополнительным параметром

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name=u'Группа')
    name = models.CharField(u'Название товара', max_length=128)
    price = models.DecimalField(u'Стоимость единицы, руб.', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    brand = models.ManyToManyField(Brand, related_name='products')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def discounted_price(self, user=None):
        return float(self.price) * self.max_discount(user=user) / 100

    def max_discount(self, user=None):
        brand_q = Q(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Brand), object_id__in=self.brand.all().values('id'))
        category_q = Q(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Category), object_id=self.category.id)
        product_q = Q(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Product), object_id=self.id)
        attr_q = Q(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Attributes), object_id__in=self.attributes.all().values('id'))
        if user:
            user_q = Q(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User), object_id=user.id)
        else:
            user_q = Q(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User), object_id=None)

        discounts = Discount.objects.filter(brand_q | category_q | user_q | product_q | attr_q, start_date__lte=timezone.now(), end_date__gt=timezone.now()).\
            aggregate(max_discount=Max('discount'))

    # discounts = Discount.objects.filter(brand_q | category_q | user_q | product_q | attr_q,
    #                                     start_date__lte=timezone.now()).\
    #     aggregate(max_discount=Max('discount'))

    return discounts['max_discount'] if discounts['max_discount'] else 0.0

class Discount(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    discount = models.FloatField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{} "{}": {}'.format(self.content_type.name, self.content_object, self.discount)
```

Как можно вставить эту функцию в queryset. Хотелось бы что нибудь подобное, но, ясно - это не работает.

```
Product.objects.all().annotate(discounted_price=discounted_price(user=user)).order_by('discounted_price')
```

Comment: Непонятно назначение some_field, field1, field2, annotate. Опишите конкретней какого результата вы хотите добиться. Пока ничего не понятно.

Comment: Аннотировать queryset результатом вызова функций нельзя. Объясните чего вы хотите добиться и покажите больше кода, возможно, нам удастся обойтись без my_property. Либо придётся делать постобработку данных.

Comment: Изменил код. Надеюсь сейчас все понятнее. Необходимо данные сортировать по цене со скидкой. Скидка может быть по нескольким моделям (скидка на бренд, категорию, сам товар или персональная скидка у пользователя). Для правильной сортировки нужно делать это при запросе к БД)

Answer (score 0):

Просто так не вышло. Пришлось идти "иным путем": создал менеджер с трехэтажным SQL

```
class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def with_discounted_price(self):
        today = timezone.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        query = '''
                  SELECT ("shop_product"."price" - ("shop_product"."price" * CASE WHEN MAX("shop_discount"."discount") IS NULL THEN 0.00 ELSE MAX("shop_discount"."discount") END / 100)) AS "discounted_price" FROM "shop_discount" WHERE
                  (
                    (( "shop_discount"."object_id" IN ( SELECT U0."id" FROM "shop_brand" U0 INNER JOIN "shop_product_brand" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."brand_id") WHERE U1."product_id" = "shop_product"."id" ) AND "shop_discount"."content_type_id" = %s )
                    OR ( "shop_discount"."object_id" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM "shop_attributes" U0 WHERE U0."product_id" = "shop_product"."id") AND "shop_discount"."content_type_id" = %s ))
                    OR ("shop_discount"."object_id" = "shop_product"."category_id" AND "shop_discount"."content_type_id" = %s)
                    OR ("shop_discount"."object_id" = "shop_product"."id" AND "shop_discount"."content_type_id" = %s)
                    AND "shop_discount"."start_date" <= %s AND "shop_discount"."end_date" >= %s
                  )
                '''
        query_params = (
                ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Brand).pk,
                ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Attributes).pk,
                ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Category).pk,
                ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Product).pk,
                today, today,)

        qs = self.get_queryset()
        qs = qs.extra(select={'discounted_price': query}, select_params=query_params)
        return qs
```